# Property type 'MyViewModel' does not match that of the 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type

Tags: swift, mvvm, option-type, weak-references, property-wrapper

I have a property wrapper to avoid dealing with implicitly unwrapped optionals.

It works great except when I try to use a custom wrapper to handle weak properties:

```
@propertyWrapper
public struct WeakMaybeUninitialized<T: AnyObject> {
    
    private weak var storage: AnyObject?
    
    public var wrappedValue: T 
 {
        get { return storage as! T }
        set { storage = newValue }
    }
    
    public init(storage: T? = nil) {
        self.storage = storage
    }
    
    public init() {}
}
```

Assuming I have the following protocol:

```
protocol ViewModel: AnyObject {}
```

Now it looks like this:

```
weak var viewModel: MyViewModel!
```

But when I use the property wrapper:

```
@WeakMaybeUninitialized var viewModel: MyViewModel
```

It returns the error "Property type 'MyViewModel does not match that of the 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type 'WeakMaybeUninitialized'"

**Even while MyViewModel actually conforms to AnyObject**, so I don't understand what happen.

Do you have a idea why?

Comment: Copy-pasting your code + presumably you meant to make `class MyViewModel: ViewModel { }`, I don't get any error.

Comment: Hi! Which version of Xcode do you use? I have 12.4 and I do get the error i mentioned.

Comment: 12.2 - tried in Playground